# Mongodb $regex PlanExecutor error during aggregation error

Tags: regex, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using MongoDB 7.0.0 on Ubuntu 22.04. When I ran this aggregation, or similar aggregation with $regex:

```
[
   {
      "$match": {
         "store.active": true,
         "$and": [
            {
               "simcard.phone_number": {
                  "$regex": '692495', 
                 "$options": "i"
               }
            },
            {
               "simcard.phone_number": {
                  "$regex": '^.{0}[0]',
                 "$options": "i"
               }
            }
         ],
         "status": "active"
      }
   },
   {
      "$skip": 0
   },
   {
      "$limit": 12
   },
   {
      "$set": {
         "store.owner": "$owner"
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup": {
         "from": "users-permissions_user",
         "localField": "owner",
         "foreignField": "_id",
         "as": "owner"
      }
   },
   {
      "$unwind": {
         "path": "$owner",
         "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
      }
   },
   {
      "$lookup": {
         "from": "inventories",
         "localField": "inventory",
         "foreignField": "_id",
         "as": "inventory"
      }
   },
   {
      "$unwind": {
         "path": "$inventory",
         "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true
      }
   },
   {
      "$sort": {
         "rand": -1
      }
   }
]
```

It sometimes gives me an error:
`PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: Unable to resolve afd05681-3b86-47ff-b60a-768a98136a19`
And in the database I see a lot of these in the logs
`Failed to remove drop-pending ident collection-49940-3694126745232387792`

It worked just fine on. Mongodb V.4.0.3 with no errors at all. I'm unsure of what to do as it happens quite often, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. When I remove the $regex and try, it works just fine. I tested this quite a few times and never got any errors when running the aggregation without $regex. Does anyone have any ideas on what I could try?